# Symfony2.8: best use of Varnish for ERP application

Tags: php, symfony, varnish, varnish-vcl, symfony-2.8

I've built a fully featured ERP platform in Symfony 2.8 + MySQL. Now I'm focusing on improving performances of the platform, and I'm evaluating Varnish and FOSHttpcachebundle adoption. But I've some doubts:

The main one is: being an ERP, one page is related to another. Easy example: I go to "Payments methods" page and I add a new payment method. Then I visit the Single Customer page and here I see the available Payments Methods. Perfect. Let's suppose this page gets cached.
Then I come back to "Payments methods" page and I add a new payment.
Then I come back to the Single Customer page and....if it has been cached, I will not see the newly added Payment Method!

I know I can invalidate the cache for a specific page, but here I would have to invalidate all the pages that refers to "Payments methods"...if we consider that relations like this are the basis of an ERP, basically every page cache will be cleared within 2-3 operations....making caching implementation useless.

I'm not experienced with caching systems so maybe my problem has been already addressed by experts on the field. Would like to ask for your advices in terms of approach.

Thanks

Comment: are you using Doctrine as an ORM?

Comment: No, I'm using ->conn->execute($query) I don't like working with doctrine entities!

Comment: so what is your purpose for caching anyway? caching makes sense for results which are pretty stable and expensive to get. as you describe it you don't seem to have one of those. that's why I go with answer by Daniel V.

Answer (score 1):

Surely enough, if your application is mostly dynamic in its nature - caching is not always desirable or possible. I think in your use case, [Edge Side Includes](https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_cache/esi.html) is something you should really look at implementing.